# Access the current user in Cucumber features - Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cucumber, integration-testing

Note: I am very new to Cucumber.

I am trying to make a generalized step (not sure if one already exists somewhere or not) so that you can easily add objects to another object, given the association exists. I want to do something like:

manage_notes.feature

```
Background: Login User
  Given the following user records
    | email          | password |
    | test@email.com | password |
  Given I am logged in as "test@email.com" with password "password"

Scenario: Edit existing note
  Given I have already created a note that belongs to current_user
```

general_steps.rb

```
Given /^the following (.+) records?$/ do |factory, table|
  table.hashes.each do |hash|
    Factory(factory, hash)
  end
end

Given /^I am logged in as "([^\"]*)" with password "([^\"]*)"$/ do |email, password|
  unless email.blank?
    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in "Email", :with => email
    fill_in "Password", :with => password
    click_button "Sign In"
  end
end
```

note_steps.rb

```
  Given /^I have already created a (.+) that belongs to (.+)$/ do |factory, resource|
      model = Factory(factory)
      resource.send(model.class.to_s.downcase.pluralize) << model
  end
```

Seems like there might be a way to use the devise 'current_user' helper.

What is the correct way to accessing the user that is logged in?

Please let me know if you need more information.
Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:**
I have temporarily fixed my issue by creating a new step that allows me to do:

```
Given I have already created a note that is owned by the user with email "test@email.com"
```

But I don't want to specify the email, I'd still like to be able to use the logged in user if possible.

**UPDATE 2:**
Added general_steps.rb

So you can see, that in my 'Background', the user is created via a Factory, and then is logged in via my interface. I want to access the model of that logged in User.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use Devise, so I can't answer specifically to if Devise has method of access the `current_user`.

But I actually like to use [Pickle](https://github.com/ianwhite/pickle) to help me keep my references. And perhaps this can help you out till you find a more Devise specific way to achieve what you want.

```
Given /^the following (.+) records$/ do |factory, table|
  table.hashes.each do |hash|
    Factory(factory, hash)

    # since this is like an all encompassing factory creator, this line to 
    # create a Pickle references might need a bit more extra work if you want
    # to create references for other factory types

    # I assume email is unique, else use a unique identifier of some sort
    find_model! %{user: "#{hash['email']}"}, {:email => hash['email']} 
  end
end

Given /^I have already created a (.+) that belongs to #{capture_model}$/ do |factory, name|
  model = Factory(factory)
  ref = model!(name) # we find that reference here
  ref.send(model.class.to_s.downcase.pluralize) << model
end
```

This would read

```
Given I have already created a note that belongs to user: "test@email.com"

# I would just change this to 
Given I have already created a note

# or
Given a note was created for user: "test@email.com"
```

You are `I` since you said `Given I logged in...`, no need to say `that belongs to user: "test@email.com"` it's already `you`.

Not to mention it could lead to confusion when you read it, some people may think you are adding a note to a user, who they might now know (or realize) is actually yourself.

---

While you still have to reference explicitly (eg. user: "John Doe"), I think that is a plus. By always calling specific references, everyone knows who is being referenced and there is no question about who is doing what to what.

Pickle serves us very well for this purpose. The only problematic areas we find are with things created directly through the app's ui, which gets a bit tricky to ensure you are creating the right reference to it.

Pickle has a large number of uses so definitely take a look.

---

**Upate**

You will have to find yourself here. Since, like you wanted, there is no `current_user` option (as far as we know). So you basically have to go find the "actor" in this scenario.

```
Given /^I have already created a note$/ do
  user = model!(%{user: "test@email.com"}) # if using pickle
  # user = User.find_by_email("test@email.com") # if just regular AR
  user.notes << Note.create
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the time you have put into this. I have marked it as useful. I will examine it in more detail at a more convenient time and will determine if it's a solution for me.

Comment: Okay, you are absolutely correct in that I should drop the 'that belongs to user: ' part. How do I access 'me' though? I want to do 'I have already created a note'. In my step, I could use the 'Given a note exists with content: "Hello", but how would I assign the user_id to be the logged in user?

Comment: I guess I'm having the most difficult trying to figure out who 'I' is in my steps. I can do 'I am logged in as 'email' with password 'password' just fine. But then when I want to do 'I have already created a note', how do I get the reference for the logged in user?

Comment: I updated the answer to give you an example of how to find yourself (or at least how I would find myself). You will have to manage who that "I" is through your tests. Either through a gem like `pickle`, or another way. Sorry for late reply, gotta bring home the bacon.

Comment: I know what you mean, haha, no problem about the late reply. It just doesn't seem like a good idea to hard code the email into the custom step. If I have to change the email in my "Background" of the feature, then I'd have to change it in multiple places. Do you understand?

Comment: I definitely understand. However, when I write a features it's to test a design or "feature", the particular actors and givens/whens/thens are all planned out. So my steps are tailored. But, as reusable, in [and out of] the contexts they are needed, as they can be. If I might say, when I started with cucumber it took me a bit of time to separate the "English" part of it all from the actual "testing" part.

Comment: You have greatly assisted me with this. I'm going to mark this as answer and award you the bounty. As this is a solution. Others are free to submit their ideas if they desire.

Answer (score 3):

I just solve it very simple:
I have "FactoryGirl" user defined, then this method...

```
Given(/^I am users logged in as "(.*?)" with password "(.*?)"$/) do |email, pass|
  visit new_user_session_path
  fill_in "user_email", :with => email
  fill_in "user_password", :with => pass
  click_button I18n.t("login.sign_in")
  @current_user = User.find_by_email(email)
end
```

further on You could use @current_user in Your steps

Answer (score 2):

This topic is quite old, but here is the solution I use. You must load this module, in env.rb, for example. Using it you can access the current user using either @current_user or current_user in your steps.

```
module UserSessionHelper
  def current_user
    @current_user
  end

  def login(user=nil)
    if user.nil?
      @current_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, username: fake_name)
    else
      @current_user = user
    end
    visit login_path
    fill_in 'Username', with: @current_user.username
    fill_in 'Password', with: '1234'
    click_button 'Login'
    page.should have_content('Logout')
  end

  def logout
    click_link 'Logout'
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include UserSessionHelper
end if RSpec.respond_to?(:configure)

World(UserSessionHelper) if respond_to?(:World)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use context for this:
http://cuke4ninja.com/sec_sharing_context.html

Have a step where you login as a user, store it in a shared context accessible to all steps and then just access it in following steps.

Hope this makes steps and I did not misinterpret the question.

Good luck with that!

Comment: From your description, it sounds like something that just runs before each scenario though right? That's not exactly what I want. I already have the Background that runs before each step, in that background, the user logs in. I'm just not sure how to 'access' the User model of the user that is currently logged in. In devise I can just call "current_user".

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I want, unless I'm misunderstanding it.

Comment: The way it works in java(I only used the java implementation) is that you define a context that will be injected in each step.
So in a first login step you perform the login steps and set your variable current_user and from this context object that is available to every other step you can then reference the variable current_user.
Does this help?

Comment: I will take a look into this again at work tomorrow. I feel there is an easier way. Have you worked with Rails/Devise before?

Comment: Nope never, I just used cucumber+wbdriver to test a website UI.

Comment: I'm not going to attempt to implement this yet. I want to hear from others as well. I want to know what the Rails Way is for doing this task.

Comment: The link now goes to a website with dating advice :(